# Django utf8 title not showing in admin

Tags: django, utf-8, django-admin

I have created this simple model:

```
from django.db import models
from slugify import *

class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField()
    pub_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    visits = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
     #approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
         return unicode(self.title)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.title = slugify(self.title)
        super(News, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from news.models import News


admin.site.register(News)
```

Whenever I create a news content in the admin panel with a Persian title, the title does not display on the panel. When the title is in ascii characters, there is not such problem

My Django version is 1.5.5 and mysql database is utf8. I've added this to settings.py (though not sure it is relevant!)

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
```

So appreciate your hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect the problem is that you're using the slugify function, which explicitly strips out non-ASCII characters.

I'm not sure why you want to slugify the title in the first place, but you might want to look into the new [awesome-slugify](http://pydanny.com/awesome-slugify-human-readable-url-slugs-from-any-string.html) library, which deals correctly with those characters.